# Understanding dictionaries, adding new values to the dictionary using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization

If I have Customer object which have Payment property which is dictionary of custom enum type and decimal value like

```
Customer.cs
public enum CustomerPayingMode
{
   CreditCard = 1,
   VirtualCoins = 2, 
   PayPal = 3
}
public Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode, decimal> Payment;
```

In client code I have problem with adding values to the Dictionary, tried like this

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.Payment = new Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode,decimal>()
                      .Add(CustomerPayingMode.CreditCard, 1M);
```

Comment: @Lunivore that was an invalid edit.

Comment: Hm, really? Okay; can someone who has a better idea of editing add an actual question then, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) methode does not return a value which you can assign to `cust.Payment`, you need to create the dictionary then call the Add() methode of the created Dictionary object:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.Payment = new Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode,decimal>();
cust.Payment.Add(CustomerPayingMode.CreditCard, 1M);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [initialize the dictionary inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531208.aspx):

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.Payment = new Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode, decimal>()
{
    { CustomerPayingMode.CreditCard, 1M }
};
```

You might also want to initialize the dictionary inside of the `Customer` constructor and let users add to `Payment` without having to initialize the dictionary:

```
public class Customer()
{
    public Customer() 
    {
        this.Payment = new Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode, decimal>();
    }

    // Good practice to use a property here instead of a public field.
    public Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode, decimal> Payment { get; set; }
}

Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.Payment.Add(CustomerPayingMode.CreditCard, 1M);
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I understand `cust.Payment` is type of `Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode,decimal>` but you're assigning it the result of `.Add(CustomerPayingMode.CreditCard, 1M)`.

You'll need to do

```
cust.Payment = new Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode,decimal>();
cust.Payment.Add(CustomerPayingMode.CreditCard, 1M);
```

When you chain method calls, the result is the return value of the last call in the chain, in your case, `.Add` method. Since it returns void, it fails to cast to `Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode,decimal>`

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the dictionary, adding a value to it and then returning the result of the `.Add` function to your variable.

```
Customer cust = new Customer();

// Set the Dictionary to Payment
cust.Payment = new Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode, decimal>();

// Add the value to Payment (Dictionary)
cust.Payment.Add(CustomerPayingMode.CreditCard, 1M);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add values to your dictionary on a separate line:

```
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.Payment = new Dictionary<CustomerPayingMode, decimal>();
    cust.Payment.Add(CustomerPayingMode.CreditCard, 1M);
```